# How to open MainWindow from a SplashScreen without button in Pyqt5?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I am trying to create a loading screen because my MainWindow takes over 10 seconds to open, which is ok as long as I have a loading screen.

Here I have some code and when i run it, it will open a loading screen.

After the loading screen pops up i want it to immediately try to open the MainWindow. (On my actual app this would take 10 seconds to open)
I have used time.sleep to simulate the time my actual programme would take to open as this is just smaller code for you to read. However my real code will not include any sleep it will just naturally take 10 seconds to load.

How can I make it so once my loading screen is visible it will immediately open MainWindow? Currently I have not asked it to do anything, the loading screen just opens and that's it.

What extra code do I need to make it open MainWindow?
Ideally I would like to update the progress bar as this happens but that is not nessecary for now I just want to know how to open MainWindow immediately from the loading screen, thanks.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import time   

class Ui_SplashScreen(object):    
    def setupUi(self, SplashScreen):
        SplashScreen.setObjectName("SplashScreen")
        SplashScreen.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(SplashScreen)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.progressBar = QtWidgets.QProgressBar(self.centralwidget)
        self.progressBar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(190, 220, 461, 91))
        self.progressBar.setProperty("value", 24)
        self.progressBar.setObjectName("progressBar")
        SplashScreen.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(SplashScreen)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        SplashScreen.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(SplashScreen)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        SplashScreen.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)   
        self.retranslateUi(SplashScreen)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(SplashScreen)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        time.sleep(10)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(310, 180, 341, 161))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(40)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "MY APP"))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    SplashScreen = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_SplashScreen()
    ui.setupUi(SplashScreen)
    SplashScreen.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not modify the code generated by pyuic so you must recreate those files that for my solution will be splash_ui.py and main_ui.py.

The idea is that the time consuming task should not run in the main thread but in a secondary thread and emit signals when it starts and ends that show and hide the splashscreen.

```
import threading
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject, pyqtSignal
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow

from main_ui import Ui_MainWindow
from splash_ui import Ui_SplashScreen

def long_running_function():
    import time

    time.sleep(10)

class Worker(QObject):
    started = pyqtSignal()
    finished = pyqtSignal()

    def start(self):
        threading.Thread(target=self._execute, daemon=True).start()

    def _execute(self):
        self.started.emit()
        # FIXME
        long_running_function()
        self.finished.emit()


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)


class SplashScreen(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.ui = Ui_SplashScreen()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    splash_screen = SplashScreen()
    main_window = MainWindow()

    worker = Worker()
    worker.started.connect(splash_screen.show)
    worker.finished.connect(splash_screen.close)    
    worker.finished.connect(main_window.show)
    worker.start()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: thankyou, my problem is that in the `main()` function when I assign `main_window = MainWindow()` it calls the `MainWindow` class and then calls `self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()`, this actually calls my time consuming task before threading starts so I still have to wait 10 seconds before threading even begins. Basically when I assign the variables in the `main()` function, before threading, it has to run my time consuming task. How can i avoid this? `setupUi()` within my Ui_MainWindow class is what takes 10seconds. I want my splash screen to load before I assign my main_window. How can I solve this?

Comment: @terrencemckenna If you re-read my answer you will see that I indicate that the task that consumes a lot of time (that is, the real code of time.sleep must move to the _execute method). You must implement the logic of the task that takes you no longer in MainWindow (that code must be restored with pyuic5) but in the part where I have placed the "#FIXME"

Comment: The problem I find is that `setupUi` *is* the code that I want to replace time.sleep with. My setupUi function in Ui_MainWindow *is* the function that I want to put in `long_running_function():`. There are around 100 buttons loading with css this is what is taking the time so how can i put setupUi in long running function, while also doing `self.ui.setupUi(self)` in the MainWindow class?

Comment: @terrencemckenna plop, you should have pointed that out since my answer assumes something else, so if you want help then provide a real MRE as the time.sleep does not mimic what you are pointing out

Comment: Hi thankyou, interestingly I have found that the reason my `setupUi` function is taking so long is because of one line of code `self.centralwidget.setStyleSheet("background-image: url(starfieldcopy.jpg);")` for some reason if I remove this line of code my app opens instantly and I no longer have to wait at all! Except my background is now missing. So for some reason the way I am setting my background in style sheet for centralwidget is causing the app to take 10 seconds to open. I think I need to set my background to something other than central widget, do you have any ideas here?

Comment: @terrencemckenna Without a [MRE] then I can't help you

Comment: I have solved my problem! Thankyou it works great now.